# Behaviour of Options inside for comprehension is Scala

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, scala-option

Two newbie questions.

It seems that `for` comprehension knows about `Options` and can skip  automatically `None` and unwrap `Some`, e.g.

```
val x = Map("a" -> List(1,2,3), "b" -> List(4,5,6), "c" -> List(7,8,9))
val r = for {map_key <- List("WRONG_KEY", "a", "b", "c")
             map_value <- x get map_key } yield map_value
```

outputs:

```
r: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))
```

**Where do the `Options` go? Can someone please shed some light on how does this work? Can we always rely on this behaviour?**

The second things is why this does not compile?

```
val x = Map("a" -> List(1,2,3), "b" -> List(4,5,6), "c" -> List(7,8,9))
val r = for {map_key <- List("WRONG_KEY", "a", "b", "c")
                 map_value <- x get map_key
                 list_value <- map_value
    } yield list_value
```

It gives

```
Error:(57, 26) type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: Option[?]
             list_value <- map_value
                        ^
```

**Looking at the type of the first example, I am not sure why we need to have an `Option` here?**

Answer (score 1):

For comprehensions are converted into calls to sequence of map or flatMap calls. See [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html)

Your `for` loop is equivalent to

```
List("WRONG_KEY", "a", "b", "c").flatMap(
  map_key => x.get(map_key).flatMap(map_value => map_value)
)
```

`flatMap` in `Option` is defined as

```
 @inline final def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B]
```

So it is not allowed to pass `List` as argument as you are notified by compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference is due to the way for comprehensions are expanded into map() and flatMap method calls within the Seq trait.

For conciseness, lets define some variables:

```
var keys = List("WRONG_KEY", a, b, c)
```

Your first case is equivalent to:

```
val r = keys.flatMap(x.get(_))
```

whereas your second case is equivalent to:

```
val r= keys.flatMap(x.get(_).flatMap{ case y => y })
```

I think the issue is that [Option.flatMap()](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Option.html#flatMap[B](f:A=%3EOption[B]):Option[B]) should return an Option[], which is fine in the first case, but is not consistent in the second case with what the x.get().flatMap is passed, which is a List[Int].

These for-comprehension translation rules are explained in further detail in chapter 7 of "Programming Scala" by Wampler & Payne.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this small difference, setting parenthesis and calling flatten, makes it clear:

```
val r = for {map_key <- List("WRONG_KEY", "a", "b", "c")
     |             } yield x get map_key 

r: List[Option[List[Int]]] = List(None, Some(List(1, 2, 3)), Some(List(4, 5, 6)), Some(List(7, 8, 9)))

val r = (for {map_key <- List("WRONG_KEY", "a", "b", "c")
     |             } yield x get map_key).flatten 

r: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))
```

That's equivalent to:

```
scala> List("WRONG_KEY", "a", "b", "c").map (x get _)
res81: List[Option[List[Int]]] = List(None, Some(List(1, 2, 3)), Some(List(4, 5, 6)), Some(List(7, 8, 9)))

scala> List("WRONG_KEY", "a", "b", "c").map (x get _).flatten
res82: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))
```

The intermediate value (map_key) vanished as _ in the second block.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up two different monads (`List` and `Option`) inside the for statement. This sometimes works as expected, but not always. In any case, you can trasform options into lists yourself:

```
for {
  map_key <- List("WRONG_KEY", "a", "b", "c")
  list_value <- x get map_key getOrElse Nil 
} yield list_value
```